# Point Addition on Elliptic Curves Over Finite Fields, Geometrically.

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

I am studying elliptic curves. A part of it is doing point addition between two points $P$ and $Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are distinct points, on a curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b (\bmod p)$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-zero integers and $p$ is some prime, so that $P+Q=R$. My question is, is there a function, given $x_p$ and $x_q$, with the sign of $y_q$ known, that $f(x_p,x_q)=x_r$?

**EDIT:** It would also be nice to have a geometric approach to adding (and doubling) points on elliptic curves over finite fields.

Comment: $H(n)$ or $H(x)$ ?

Comment: Just in case nobody else said this. You really should NEVER replace your question with a totally different one. Many think that is quite rude (to those who answer the earlier version).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know that, but only one person commented, so I thought that it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

---

Some words follow, to explain how i understood the question, and why i claim the negative answer. An example may make the situation simpler to explain. Let us consider over $F=\Bbb F_p$, $p=11$, the elliptic curve with equation $y^2=x^3 + x + 1$. Then on the curve we have the rational points
$$ P_\pm = (0,\pm 1)\ ,\qquad Q_\pm=(1,\pm 5)\ .$$
Then

- the "two $P$-points" have the same $x$-component, $x_p=0$,
- the "two $Q$-points" have the same $x$-component, $x_q=1$,

but adding points in all four possible ways to combine deliver, here in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( GF(11), [1, 1] )
sage: P0, P1 = E.point( (0, +1) ), E.point( (0, -1) )
sage: Q0, Q1 = E.point( (1, +5) ), E.point( (1, -5) )
sage: [ (P+Q).xy() for P in [P0, P1] for Q in [Q0, Q1] ]
[(4, 5), (2, 0), (2, 0), (4, 6)]
```

we get the above points, the first coordinate is either $2$, or $4$. So there is no "unique $x_r$" that can be associated only with the knowledge of $x_p$, $x_q$.

---

The reason can be simply explained by the fact, that the computation of $R$ depends of building the following slope $m$ in the affine plane of the rational points $P(x_p,y_p)$, $Q(x_q,y_q)$, 
$$
m = \frac{y_p-y_q}{x_p-x_q}\ .
$$
So exchanging signs in $\pm y_p$, $\pm y_q$ leads "very often" to a difference.

---

**Bonus:** Here are some further thoughts related to the geometrical construction of $P+Q$ and $2P:=P+P$ for two points $P,Q$ on some elliptic curve defined over some finite field $F=\Bbb F_q$, $q$ prime power (of a prime not equal to two, three maybe), or over an infinite field $F=\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, by an equation of the shape:
$$
E\ :\ y^2 =x^3+ax+b\ ,\ a,b\in F\ ,
$$
where $x^3+ax+b$ has different roots in some algebraic closure of $F$.

We start with two $F$-rational points $P_1(x_1,y_1)$, and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$ in $E(F)$. In the generic case $x_1\ne x_2$ the equation of the line through the two points is of the shape $y=mx+n$, with $m,n$ depending on $P_1$, $P_2$. Then from 
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 &=mx_1+n\ ,\\
y_2 &=mx_2+n\ ,&&\text{ after subtraction we get}\\
y_1-y_2&=m(x_1-x_2)\ ,&&\text{ so we have the formula for the slope $m$}\\
m &=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For the first coordinate $x_3$ of $\pm (P_1+P_2)=(x_3,\pm y_3)$ we need only $m$, but $n$ can also be found easily from the above relations, then the third point on the line $P_1P_2$ (counting multiplicities) is by the definition of the operation $+$ on $E(F)$ the point $-(P_1+P_2)=(x_3,-y_3)$. (If we denote the coordinates in the sum $P_1+P_2$ by $x_3,y_3$.)

The points 
$(x_1,y_1)$, 
$(x_2,y_2)$, 
$(x_3,-y_3)$ satisfy thus both equations $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and $y=mx+n$. We eliminate $y$ using the second equation from the first one, so
$$
x^3+ax+b-(mx+n)^2=0\ .
$$
Explicitly:
$$
x^3-m^2x^2+\text{(lower degree terms in $x$)}=0
$$
has then the roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Vieta gives us for the sum
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3 = m^2\ ,
$$
so we obtain the formula for the first coordinate $x_3$, which is
algebraically
$$
\boxed{\qquad
\begin{aligned}
x_3 &=-x_1-x_2+m^2
\\
&=-x_1-x_2+\left(\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}\right)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
\qquad}
$$
This is a good point to check the formula for some points on some curve. I will work first with $E$ given by $y^2=x^3+x+1$ over $F=\Bbb F_{11}$, ask for the sum of some random points $P,Q$ in $E(F)$.
We ask for the implemented formula, thus getting $P+Q$ from sage, then i will implement with bare hands the above formula, also ask for the result for the same points.

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( GF(11), [1, 1] )
sage: import random
sage: P = random.choice(E.points())
sage: Q = random.choice(E.points())
sage: P, Q, P+Q
((2 : 0 : 1), (0 : 10 : 1), (1 : 6 : 1))
sage: def x3(P, Q):
....:     """We compute the first component x3 of P=:(x1, y1), Q=:(x2, y2)
....:     using the formula x3 = -x1 -x2 + (y1-y2)^2/(x1-x2)^2
....:     Note that we assume x1 != x2, and that P, Q != infinit point"""
....:     x1, y1 = P.xy()
....:     x2, y2 = Q.xy()
....:     return -x1 -x2 + (y1-y2)^2/(x1-x2)^2
....: 
....:     
sage: x3(P, Q)
1
sage: # the abover is the first component of P+Q = (1, 6)
```

Let us use some "more convincing" framework.

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( QQ, [1, 1] )
sage: E.rank()
1
sage: E.gens()
[(0 : 1 : 1)]
sage: G = E.point( (0, 1) )    # the generator
sage: P, Q = 7*G, -5*G
sage: P, Q
((-3596697936/8760772801 : 591456591665497/819999573400799 : 1),
 (43992/82369 : 30699397/23639903 : 1))
sage: P+Q
(1/4 : -9/8 : 1)
sage: x3(P, Q)
1/4
sage: P-Q
(516800901506579137034097949153/116165201153061098261023776144
 : 382844998133375068925120757216593508841494737/39592604638617085219380314122331748004030272
 : 1)
sage: x3(P, -Q)
516800901506579137034097949153/116165201153061098261023776144
```

A last remark about doubling. We start with "$P$ and $P$", and need to get the corresponding line $y=mx+n$ again. We use the notation $P(x_1,y_1)$, compute $2P=(x_3,y_3)$, but only the first component. (The second one follows, typing is only harder.)

One possibility to proceed is as follows. The point $P(x_1,y_1)$ is on the curve with equation $F(x,y)=0$, where $F(x,y)=x^3+ax+b-y^2$. Let us write $x=x_1+s$, $y=y_1+t$ to get in the Taylor expansion of $F$ around $(x_1,y_1)$ quickly the linear term. Explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x,y)
&=(x_1+s)^3+a(x_1+s)+b-(y_1+t)^2
\\
&=\underbrace{(x_1^3+ax_1+b-y_1^2)}_{=0}
+(3x_1^2s+as-2y_1t)
+\text{(Higher order monomials in $s,t$)}\ .\\[3mm]
\operatorname{Taylor}_1(F)(x,y)
&=
3x_1^2s+as-2y_1t
\\
&=(3x_1^2+a)(x-x_1)-2y_1(y-y_1)\ .\\[3mm]
&\text{Compare with $y=mx+n$. So the needed slope $m$ is}
\\
m &=\frac{3x_1^2+a}{2y_1}\ .\\[3mm]
&\text{Alternatively:}
\\
m &=
\lim\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
\\
&=\lim\frac{(y_2-y_1)(y_2+y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)(y_2+y_1)}
\\
&=\lim\frac{y_2^2-y_1^2}{(x_2-x_1)(y_2+y_1)}
\\
&=\lim\frac{(x_2^3+ax_2+b)-(x_1^3+ax_1+b)}{(x_2-x_1)(y_2+y_1)}
\\
&=\lim\frac{x_2^2+x_1x_2+x_1^2+a}{y_2+y_1}
\\
&=\frac{x_1^2+x_1x_1+x_1^2+a}{y_1+y_1}
\\
&=\frac{3x_1^2+a}{2y_1}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(The limit is taken for $(x_2,y_2)$ converging on the curve to $(x_1,y_1)$.
From here, we have the same, so $x_3=-x_1-x_1+m^2$. Computer check:

```
sage: def x3_for_double(P):
....:     """We compute the first component x3 for 3P for P=:(x1, y1),
....:     using the formula x3 = -2x1 + (3*x1^2+a)^2/4/y1^2
....:     """
....:     x1, y1 = P.xy()
....:     a = P.curve().a4()
....:     m = (3*x1^2 + a) / 2 / y1
....:     return -2*x1 + m^2
....: 
sage: twoP.xy()[0]    # first component of 2P
23419679382776533016338728874246651427713/12258805697617629893689847027495187248836
sage: x3_for_double(P)
23419679382776533016338728874246651427713/12258805697617629893689847027495187248836

sage: # here, P has the last value used above
sage: P
(-3596697936/8760772801 : 591456591665497/819999573400799 : 1)
```

**Note:** All the above is "naive and standard", but i tried to write down explicitly the algebraic geometry computations. Monographs do not have the space for this, courses do not have the time.

Comment: First, how is $(1,5)$ a point? And two, lets say the sign of $y_p$ is known. Even if the sign of $y_q$ is negative or positive, would there be a difference in $x_r$?

Comment: Let us see if $(1,5)$ is a point. (Sage would not accept the code else.) We have to check $5^2=1^3+1^1+1$, which holds over the field $F$ with $11$ elements. (It is natural to look for examples over finite fields, when typing denominators may be soon an issue over rationals when adding points. And the OP also mentions some modulo $p$.) Then the "sign" makes no sense, which is for instance the sign of $5$, or of $6$ in the field $F$ with $11$ elements? "Knowing which one of the values of $\pm y$" of a point $(x,y)$ is taken may lead to a function $f$ as in the $OP$, but not an algebraic one.

Comment: Oh so $5^2 \mod 11=1^3+1^1+1$ I always thought that $y^2=x^3+x+1 \mod 11$ must be true to be a point.

Comment: To be sure that the message arrived, yes, we have explicitly modulo $11$ the equality $5^2=25=3+22=3+0=3=1+1+1$.

Comment: Oh, I got it: $y^2 \bmod p=x^3+ax+b \bmod p$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the game. You may find it useful to play with sage, which covers in a simple and structural way (using the language of mathematics) all existing algorithms concerning elliptic curves (over $\Bbb Q$ and/or over a finite field). Programming knowledge is an advantage, but simply using it as a command line tool may also be very useful. For instance http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/elliptic_curves.html#the-gf-q-rational-points-on-e but many other documented features.

Comment: I usually code in Python, but will give it a go. I'm more focused on the equations, however.

Comment: Then you're home, sage is written in python, collects all existing free and less free maths software (alias CAS ~ computer algebra systems) like pari/gp, Cremona database, maxima, R, etc. and uses python as a "general parser", most sage libraries are written in python + batteries, numpy and/or scipy are already included in implemented algorithms (or sage uses the existing implementation), but can also be imported. Sage comes with the sage console, a kind of ipython (with preprocessing). Equations are of course also supported. Questions can be directed to https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/

Comment: I'll accept your answer (which is great by the way) after if you can tell me how to approach the addition and doubling of points geometrically.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried the formula -x1 -x2 + (y1-y2)^2/(x1-x2)^2 on Desmos for (2,0) and (0,10) and I got 23,  rather than 1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remember once for all times, we are working modulo $11$. So computations like addition, multiplication can be done in $\Bbb Z$, but at the end the result is taken modulo $11$, we are working in $$F=\Bbb F_{11}=\Bbb Z/11\ ,$$ so $\dots=-33=-22=-11=0=11=22=33=\dots$, and $\dots=-33+1=-22+1=-11+1=0+1=11+1=22+1=33+1=\dots$, and i never write that "modulo eleven", since it is clear from the context. We already saw that $25=3$, now we are at the point with $23=1$. The level of complication when dealing with elliptic curves is high, please fix first the needed knowledge. This is my last comment.

Comment: My mind just facepalmed itself when it realized $23 \mod 11$ is $1$. Thank you.